# PostgreSQL - Create an array of jsonb using group by clause

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have an SQL query that returns the data attached in the image. I would like to group the information and basically have just 2 rows (in this particular case). The row #1 would be: "evaluation_id": 1, "nombre": "Método: Jackson, Pollock & Ward" and "formulario" should be an array of json objects (in this case, records: 1,2,3 and 4). The row #2 would be: "evaluation_id": 2, "nombre": "Método: Medición Antropométrica Estándar" and "formulario" should be an array with only one json object (record #5).

| evaluation_id | nombre | formulario |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jackson, Pollock & Ward | [{json1},{json2},{json3},{json4}] |
| 2 | Medición Antropométrica Estándar | [{json5}] |

I have tried with functions like: array_to_json, json_object, json_aggr, json_array_elements but I couldn't make it work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the output of this query your expected

```sql
-- if use json type
select evaluation_id, nombre, json_agg(formulario)
from your_table
group by 1, 2

-- if use jsonb type
select evaluation_id, nombre, jsonb_agg(formulario)
from your_table
group by 1, 2
```

Comment: Thank you @pooya, that works perfectly. What means the "group by 1, 2"?

Comment: Your welcome, `group 1, 2` means `group evaluation_id, nombre`. You can use column number instead column name in group by

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks for all your help @Pooya, I really appreciate it.